# Matrix exponential, $A^0=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following term in linear algebra: $$e^{Ax}$$, where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ is a column vector. A neat idea is to express this as power series. However, my question concerns the first term in the expansion. We know that:

$$e^x = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}$$

So,

$$e^{Ax} = (Ax)^0 + Ax + ...$$

Now why is $(Ax)^0=I$ and how is this operation valid at all. We have a matrix and we raise it to the power of zero. My initial guess was to use the following result:

$$A^{k}x=\lambda x$$
Provided that the eigenvectors of $A$ are linearly independent. So I would have that:

$$A^0x=\lambda^0x$$
$$A^0x=x$$

So does this actually imply that $A^0=I$? What values of $k$ are valid for $A^kx=\lambda^k x$ and why? Can we use negative integers? (I know that to prove that formula, one can multiply: $Ax=\lambda x$ by $A$: $A^2x=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2x$; so I would assume only $\mathbb{Z}^+$ are valid; If the reasoning above is valid, then $0$ is also valid.)

Comment: Check the definition of $A^0$.

Comment: If A is non-singular then $A^{-1} A^n = A^{n-1}$ and $A^{-1}A = A^0 = I$

Comment: This is neat. Does that stem from the definitions of matrix operations? It is non trivial to me why that is the case and why we should have a non singular matrix for that to work

Comment: Why non-singular, $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist for singular matrices, and it may be the case that $A^n = 0$.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thanks. What about the operations in the power?